# How to call checkbox id that id value is set dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I have call data from mysql and set checkbox id dynamically with php

```
<?php
    if (isset($sls_data)) {
       foreach ($sls_data as $data) {
?>          
       <div class="checkbox col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">                                                                
          <label class="control-label">
              <input type="checkbox" name="<?= $data->SLSGROUP ?>" id="<?= 
               $data->SLSGROUP ?>" value="true">
               <?= $data->SLSGROUP ?>
          </label>
       </div>
   <?php
      }
    }
 ?>
```

I want to use just like 
`var i= $("#id).val();`

How can I use that. And I have to save in mysql database

Comment: How do you want to 'call checkbox id'? Show what your ajax function looks like, and what you are trying to do with the checkbox

Comment: Ahh!! I want to save that checkbox if checked save value= 1 in database else not checked save value = 0.So, how can I get that checkbox is checked or unchecked

Answer (score 0):

**1st** First of all your id attribute is dynamic so we can't hard code the id in jquery so you just use same class name for all the checkbox

**2nd :** write Onclick event handler for that  classname .

**3rd :** when click the check box while check like this `$(this).is(':checked');` to know check box is checked or not .

```js
$(document).on('click','.checkbox_grp',function(){

      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      console.log('checked true  '+1);
      else
       console.log('checked false  '+0);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">                                                                
          <label class="control-label">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_grp" name="name1" id="1" value="true">
              checkbox1
          </label>
       </div>
 <div class="checkbox col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">                                                                
          <label class="control-label">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_grp" name="name2" id="2" value="true">
              checkbox2
          </label>
       </div>
```

Comment: It's work. But if I use it, I can't get checked or unchecked for each checkbox

Comment: I didn't get you `I can't get checked or unchecked for each checkbox` ?

Comment: Each checkbox (value = true), when i checked or unchecked.

Comment: because you set the value attribute is `value="true"` so that it will always give you true weather you check or uncheck .so you have to do some logic like this .`if($(this).is(':checked'))
      var value=1;
      else
       var value=0;` like this @KhantZin